# creating dynamic updates in Agensgraph via Cypher

Tags: cypher, graphdb, agens-graph

trying to create a function like :-

```
addChild(parent graphid,child graphid,relationship text,direction text)

merge(parent)-[r:f(relationship)]->(child) return id(r);
```

with a typical cal :

```
relid=addChild(id(a),id(b),'has','U') -- where U means up child to parent
```

Question is, without a very tedious switch statement , how do I associate a text version of the relationship, or edge type, with an actual edge type?

Answer (score 0):

Took a bit of messing around and the syntax seems a bit last-minute but this works :

```
return query execute format('match(p) where id(p)=%s with p match(c) where id(c)=%s with p,c merge(p)-[r:%s]->(c)  return id(r);',parent,child,reltype);
```

Where `parent` and `child` are graph ids and `reltype` is text;